# React Native: How do we know we should add @types/packagename for specific package name in dev dependency?

Tags: typescript, react-native, package, dependencies

I am new in React Native with typescript.

For example package vector icon,  we have to add 2 dependency

```
1 is "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.1.0" in dependency

2 is "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.6", in dev dependency
```

For some package dev dependency starts with @type is is optional, how do I know its optional or not?

Answer (score 0):

If you visit the [repo for @types](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped), you can see that they provide Typescript definitions for popular NPM packages.

That's why they are only listed as a dev dependency - Typescript code is transpiled into regular Javascript before becoming production code, so you would only use Typescript definitions during development.